# My web page's layout only works on Chrome. It looks messy on other browsers. How do I format layout on CSS to accommodate for all browsers?

Tags: css

Namely the banner, buttons, and pictures (all ids)...

http://jerry.pancakeapps.com/hello.html

```
/*Basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

/* Started June 11, 2013 */

body {
    background: #B1E3E2;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 20px #80D0CF;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Put social networking icons beside name*/

table tr td {
    padding-right: 1px;
}

#social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 325px;
    top: 157px;
}

#social tr td {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

/* Added link styling June 13, 2013 */

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

These pictures are all messed up (you can see on IE, Firefox, etc.)

```
#piano {
    position: absolute;
    right: 516px;
    top: 473px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#video {
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 800px;
}

#waterloo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 110px;
    top: 473px;
}
```

Buttons are messed up as well, layout-wise...

```
#bluebutton1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 327px;
    left: 650px;
    height: 59px;
    width: 120px;
    border:2px solid #6495ED;
    background-color: #BCD2EE;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    display: block;
}

#bluebutton1:hover {
    top: 300px;
}

#orangebutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 327px;
    left: 877px;
    height: 47px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 5px dashed #FF6347;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    display: block;
}   

#orangebutton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 300px;
}

#bluebutton2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 327px;
    left: 1111px;
    height: 47px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 2px solid #6495ED;
    background-color: #BCD2EE;
    border-radius: 40px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 23px;
    display: block;
}

#bluebutton2:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 300px;
}
```

And header is messed up too.

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #8699A0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #758890;
    margin: 120px 0;
    font-family: gothic;
    outline: none;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 500px;
box-shadow: 
        0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
        0 36px 0 -18px #B1E3E2;
}

h1:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: -24.5%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 149.2%;
    height: 140px;
    border: 70px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 70px solid #B1E3E2;
    border-right: 70px solid #B1E3E2;
}

h1:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-top: 18px solid #99acb2;
    border-left: 18px solid transparent;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
}

h1, h1:before {
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(
            transparent 8%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 8%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 14%, 
            transparent 14%, 
        transparent 86%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 86%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 92%, 
            transparent 92%
        ), 
        linear-gradient(
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), 
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 
        ), 
            linear-gradient(
            45deg, 
            transparent 40%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 60%, 
            transparent 60%
        ), 
        linear-gradient(white, white); 
    background-size: 
        cover, /*borders*/
        cover, /*white gloss*/
        4px 4px, /*thin stripes*/
        cover; /*base white*/
}

h1, h1:before, h1:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-origin: border-box;
}
```

Please tell me another way to specify layout so it is cross-compatible with different browsers?

Comment: Doesn't even work in chrome (v29.0.1547.54).

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

This is broken in all browsers. Its too hard to see what you want to achieve. To get this done

- Draw boxes on a sheet of paper to represent each element on your page. This is a process called wireframing. It is like an architect's plan. It also acts like a map helps to stop you getting lost in your code.
- Using floated divs with colour backgrounds recreate the box layout you drew on the paper.
- Test it in all browsers
- Once the boxes are are layout in a grid you like replace them with your images and links.

Otherwise add a few images. Test it it all browsers. Add links. Test again in all browsers. Then add the video frame. The idea is take small steps get the code to work then move on. That way you only have the last few lines of code to look for errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use a CSS reset file to get all browsers behave very similarly.  This will provide a good foundation before you apply your own styles on top of it.

Here are a few good resources:

[Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

[YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/)

[HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)